# Fluent NHibernate Relation Without Foreign Key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying so simplify my problem here, but basically I'm trying to map 2 entities however i don't have a Foreign Key in the database set, since the column could be null. When I try to do an insert on the parent, I'm getting the following error:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to
>   something that would make it autosave.

This is what I have so far:

**My entities**

```
public class DocumentDraft
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual string ReferenceNo { get; set;}
    public virtual DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentType
{
    public virtual short Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
public class DocumentDraftMap : ClassMap<DocumentDraft>
{
    public DocumentDraft()
    {
        // other mappings ...
        References(x => x.DocumentType)
            .Columns("DocumentTypeId")
            .Nullable()
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .NotFound.Ignore(); // <-- added this since the value could be null and it throws an error
    }
}
```

I tried specifying `Cascade.None()` in the mapping, but I'm getting the same result. Basically what happens is that a `null` value is attempted at being inserted in the `DocumentType`, and I don't want this (I want to insert null in the parent table, but I don't want to touch the child tables at all, I don't want this to cascade).

I've also tried: `.Not.Insert()`, but that didn't work either.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out on this one.

Comment: are you sure the property DocumentType is null when saving? it seems there is an instance and without cascade.All() on the reference it can not be saved.

Comment: @Firo It is null when saving, and that's the problem, I want it it to be saved as null in the Database, I've been pulling my hair all day. Sometimes NHibernate can be very annoying I gotta tell ya.

Comment: @Firo Also I've edited my question a bit, since It was a bit misleading. I want to update the parent table not the child (don't want it to cascade).

Comment: @Firo, you were right, I wasn't actually passing a null (instead I was instantiating a `DocumentType` with all it's values `0` or `null`, I feel so stupid, 1 day wasted. Put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: don't worry, it happens to all of us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the property DocumentType is not really null when saving.
It seems there is an instance and without Cascade.All() on the reference it can not be saved.